# i need to show value of ng-model, but is not updating

Tags: angularjs

```
<div class="row ">
        <div class="cell size-p40 " align="right" style="border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-left-width:0px;border-top-width:0px;padding-right:3px;" >
          <h5>Rendimento Social de Inserção</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="cell size-p10 " style="align:right;border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-left-width:0px;border-top-width:0px;" >
          <div class="input-control text full-size" style="margin:0px!important;">

            <span class="prepend-icon">€</span>
            <input type="number" align="right" style="direction:RTL;" ng-model="RendimentoSocialInsercao" />
          </div>
        </div>

  </div>
<div class="row ">
      <div class="cell size-p40 " align="right" style="padding-right:3px;border:0px;border-right-width:1px;border-style:solid;" >
        <h5>Total</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="cell size-p10 " style="align:right;border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-top-width:0px;border-left-width:0px;" >
        {{totalReceitas}}
      </div>

  </div>
```

My controller is
controller.js

```
    (function() {

  var app = angular.module("caiApp");

  var cDiaController = function($scope,$log) {

    $scope.totalReceitas=$scope.RendimentoSocialInsercao;

 };

  app.controller("cDiaController",['$scope','$log',cDiaController]);

}());
```

im trying to show in {{totalReceitas}} the same value that i input in the ng-model="RendimentoSocialInsercao" but it does not update, what am i doing wrong?

PS: that is inside a form

Comment: You need to watch the other variable as it changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you would do that, but this is what you were missing.

```
(function() {

  var app = angular.module("caiApp");

  var cDiaController = function($scope,$log) {
    $scope.$watch("RendimentoSocialInsercao", function(newVal, oldVal) {
      $scope.totalReceitas=newVal;
    });    
 };

  app.controller("cDiaController",['$scope','$log',cDiaController]);

}());
```